# What is the purpose of the bb_migrate_friends_count function?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddyboss

My large and busy Production website, with a users database of close to 400,000 users, has been facing multiple-day delays for 'bb_forums_subscribed_discussion' Notifications, registered by the function bb_send_forums_subscribed_discussion() in buddyboss-platform\bp-forums\classes\class-bp-forums-notification.php

In the file buddyboss-platform\bp-core\bp-core-update.php the function bb_update_to_2_2_9() wrote in the database, in the wp_options table hundreds of thousands of rows that include the string "*batch*" in the option_name and the callback "bb_migrate_member_friends_count" saved by the function bb_create_background_member_friends_count()

It has been months since the 2.2.9 update and to this date, the database continues to be flooded with these batch processing, that is constantly executing as registered in the server logs.
All the time, the logs write this in non-stop, over and over and this started months ago, and it still has never completed.

In a local dev, when we deleted all +100K *batch* records from wp_options that registered the callback bb_migrate_friends_count, notifications went out perfectly again, like we had hoped.

We are considering deleting all of these records from our live site, but we'd like to know exactly what this "bb_migrate_member_friends_count" actually does, and if eliminating it would drastically effect our site.

Does anyone have any experience with the "bb_migrate_member_friends_count"? Would anyone happen to know what exactly it is doing?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you already ask the buddyboss folks, first?

Comment: Welcome with your first question!
To improve your question, I would suggest:
Include some real messages, error messages, logs, whatever.
Be specific!

Formatting:
You use single quotes "' " to mark code snippets or commands.
You should use instead:
for inline code or commands:
Incorrect: 'bb_forums_subscribed_discussion', bb_send_forums_subscribed_discussion().
Correct: bb_forums_subscribed_discussion, bb_send_forums_subscribed_discussion().

For code blocks:
Incorrect:
'batch' in the option_name and the callback 'bb_migrate_members_friends_count'.
Correct:
`batch` in the option_name and the c

Comment: We have consulted the Senior Technical Support at BuddyBoss for the past two months regarding the initial issue of notification delays, and received very little response. A couple of weeks ago, we came across the above theory, and our test proved that this function was indeed the problem. BuddyBoss appeared to think it over for two weeks, and finally responded with the same non-answer that we needed to provide them with an exact replica test site (which we had already done). We don't know what is going on over there, quite honestly, but we really do need to fix our issue so we're moving on.